# Finding an element in an array where consecutive elements differ by 1

Tags: algorithm

There is an array and the distance between any two consequent elements is one (+1/-1). How will you find an element in it. Can it be done in less than O(n) time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply start in first position; now consider the difference bewteen the searched number m`;` if `array[0] == m` then we finished; otherwise we have to jump of `abs(array[0] - m)` positions; now just repeat this until the end of the array. 
However, in the worst case we can't do better than O(n), just consider this case, we want to find 11:

```
10 9 8 9 8 9    10 9 8 9 8 9    10 9 8 9 8 9    10 9 8 9 8 9
```

Comment: The part between "otherwise" and "positions" does not make grammatical sense.  Can you try to repair that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple idea that should help you think about the problem.

If you are looking for `x` and `abs(x-array[0]) == k`, then you may as well jump to `array[k]`.

Think about this and you will have your algorithm.

Now, think about the worst possible case for this algorithm. Can you make it so that most entries have to be checked? (HINT: yes)